# Error when transforming (and reversing) Tuple Tuple to dict

Tags: python, string, dictionary, tuples, key

I am trying to transform following tuple tuple into a dict (and a reversed one of that):

```
EDIT_TUTORING_PLACES_CHOICES_TRANSLATOR = (
  (AT_STUDENT, ['1']),
  (AT_TUTOR, ['2']),
  (ONLINE, ['3']),
  (AT_STUDENT_AND_TUTOR, ['1', '2']),
  (AT_STUDENT_AND_ONLINE, ['1', '3']),
  (AT_TUTOR_AND_ONLINE, ['2', '3']),
  (ALL, ['1', '2', '3']),
  
)
```

This is the code I use:

```
dict = {v: k for k, v in list(EDIT_TUTORING_PLACES_CHOICES_TRANSLATOR)}
```

And I receive the following error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

How should I do this? Thank you a lot!

Comment: What are you trying to do? `dict(EDIT_TUTORING_PLACES_CHOICES_TRANSLATOR)` should work if the task is just to create dictionary. Another question is why are you initializing tuple if you need a dictionary..

Comment: Olvin Roght, I want it to be reversed

Comment: Then you should read an error message. Keys of dictionary should be hashable. You can convert list to tuple which is hashable.

Comment: That's right, I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right, lists cannot be used as keys in python dict because key has to be immutable.
However, you can archive your goal by using tuples instead of lists (as tuples are immutable)
To create your dict use

```
tutor_place_array_to_int_map = {tuple(v): k for k, v in list(EDIT_TUTORING_PLACES_CHOICES_TRANSLATOR)}
```

so that your key in dict is immutable tuple and then you will be able to use:

```
sth = tutor_place_array_to_int_map[("1", "2")]
sth = tutor_place_array_to_int_map.get(("1", "2"))
sth = tutor_place_array_to_int_map.get(tuple(["1", "2"]))
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The dict would have a list as a key, which is not possible.
I solved the problem with nested if/else statements:

```
def tutor_place_array_to_int(arr: list[str]):
  if arr.count('1') > 0:
    if arr.count('2') > 0:
      if arr.count('3') > 0:
        return ALL
      else:
        return AT_STUDENT_AND_TUTOR
    else:
      if arr.count('3') > 0:
        return AT_STUDENT_AND_ONLINE
      else:
        return AT_STUDENT
  else:
    if arr.count('2') > 0:
      if arr.count('3') > 0:
        return AT_TUTOR_AND_ONLINE
      else:
        return AT_TUTOR
    else:
      if arr.count('3') > 0:
        return ONLINE

  return None
```

ALL, AT_STUDENT_AND_TUTO, etc. are constants representing integers

Comment: Part of a tutor/student matching app ;)

Comment: So many questions.. What is the final purpose of this function? How do you call it?

Comment: import it from the same place where I store the constants, and the purpose: translate the data sent from the frontend to the format it is stored in the backend

Comment: The question was *"How do you call it?"*. Give me line of code which call this function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).